# Voltage regulator identification?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

[image]I need to identify what I think is a voltage regulator. It is a TO-220 package with 023499 at the top and 8509 below it with KAG below that. Can anyone help with this? It is in a battery charger.

Comment: No other identifying marks or manufacturer's logos?

Comment: Could you post a photo of said device. Preferably one detailed enough to see the markings. A manufacturers logo would be useful as @brhans said.

Comment: Picture added, sorry about the quality.

Answer (score 2):

it looks to me like a Motorola thyristor produced in the ninth week of 1985.  The K A G refer to the Cathode (K), anode (A) and Gate(G) pins.

The number is possibly a house number rather than a public one.

kevin

Comment: Any suggestions on a replacement for this component? It is 12V 10A battery charger. The output or charging cable (+) is connected to Gate pin.